# A combinatorial proof for a bound on diagonal Ramsey numbers

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, binomial-coefficients, ramsey-theory

I wish to prove $R(p,p)\leq\frac{2^{2p-2}}{\sqrt{p}}$ combinatorially. I have proved this algebraically through the definition of the binomial coefficient but I would much prefer a proof from combinatorics.

I have managed to get as far as $$R(p,p)\leq\binom{2p-2}{p-1}\leq2^{2p-2}$$
but I am unsure as to why the inequality still holds if we divide by $\sqrt{p}$. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Are you asking for a combinatorial proof that ${2p-2\choose p-1}\leq {2^{2p-2}\over \sqrt{p}}$?